# Automate Complex task

Tags: automation, autohotkey

There is a task that I would like to automate. Here is what I do manually:

On one side (source) I have let's say 30 Folders filled with files and Subfolders. They all have a subfolder called "instruments" somewhere inside them.

On the other (destination) I have (In a different location) 30 folders with the same names but they are all completely empty.

1. I go to the first source folder and search for the "instruments" subfolder.
2. I select everything inside the "instruments" folder.
3. I hold alt and then drag and drop the files to the corresponding empty folder (destination) to create shortcuts inside it.
4. I then have in the destination a Folder with the same name as the original, with inside it shortcuts to every file that where present in the "instruments" subfolder.

Them I repeat the task with the 2nd folder.

Can I automate this ?

Tried AHK but I don't have the knowledge to be able to produce a complex script like this.

Answer (score 0):

This VBS script ought to do the trick:

```vb
Dim src, dest
Dim fso, folder, subfolder, files
Dim count

src = "source-folder"
dest = "destination-folder"
count = 1

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(src)
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

For Each subfolder In folder.SubFolders
    Set files = fso.GetFolder(subfolder.Path).SubFolders
    
    For Each file In files
        If InStr(file.Path, "\instruments") > 0 Then
            shortcutPath = dest & "\instruments (" & count & ").lnk"
            Set shortcut = shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutPath)
            shortcut.TargetPath = file.Path
            shortcut.Save
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Copy and paste this into a text file and call it `automate.vbs`, so you can easily run it by clicking on it.

Just replace `source-folder` with the folder path containing the subfolders which contain the instrument folders, and `destination-folder` with the folder where you want the links to appear, and then run it.

Alternatively, if you're using Linux, here is a bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

src="source-folder"
dest="destination-folder"

count=1
for f in "$src"/*/*
  do
    if [[ "$f" = */instruments ]]
      then
        ln -s ./"$f" "$dest"/"instruments ($count)"
        echo "Making link to $f"
        count=$((count + 1))
    fi
done
```